# Error while merging dex archives: Program type already present: com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer$1

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to run an android studio project but everytime when I try I got this error. I don't know whats the problem is? Could you please check it and let me know what I'm doing wrong.
 In my application I didnot add com.spoledge.aacdecoder file.But It shows already present.
This is app Build Gradle:
    **build.gradle:(module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android{
     compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.somename.musicapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner <br/>"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

configurations.all {exclude group: 'com.spoledge.aacdecoder'}

dependencies{
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':theme')
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation project(':jcvideoplayer-lib')
    implementation project(':network')
    implementation project(':commonframework')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.juanpabloprado:countrypicker:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    implementation 'com.github.iammert:RadioPlayerService:efe3b5420b'<br/>
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'

}
```